# Android google account synch

Tags: android

I am working on one application. It works on C2DM. Everything is working fine. It is device tracking application. But if i change sim and restart my device my Google account is not automatically signing in  and it asks for Google account password and not getting notifications.

I want when i change my sim and restart the device Google account should automatically sync and should not ask for password.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. It's coded into the OS that a SIM change will clear all account settings. You could roll your own OS patch if you felt inclined though.